HIGHCHARTS: Border around chart legend is cut off at bottom
The thin black border around my chart legend is cut off at the bottom (image below).
This is happening in the browser and on PNG export.
The issue is caused by the adapt-chart-to-legend plugin, without which the chart is vertically short and lacks resolution on the y axis
See https://jsfiddle.net/SirMunchington/vbt6q7rk/5/ (code below)
The issue appears to persist regardless of the number of chart elements in the legend.



Highcharts.chart('container', {
    "title": {
        "text": "Goal Name: Test Goal #4",
        "style": {
            "color": "#274b6d",
            "fontSize": "16px"
        }
    },
    "subtitle": {
        "text": "Scenario Name: New Try"
    },
    "colors": [
        "#f28f43",
        "#bc8321",
        "#2f7ed8",
        "#9370db",
        "#1aadce",
        "#8bbc21",
        "#c42525"
    ],
    "chart": {
        "reflow": true,
        "backgroundColor": "transparent",
        "borderRadius": 5,
        "events": {}
    },
    "plotOptions": {
        "series": {
            "label": {
                "connectorAllowed": true
            },
            "pointStart": 2018,
            "animation": false,
            "enableMouseTracking": true,
            "stickyTracking": false,
            "shadow": false
        },
        "line": {
            "animation": false,
            "enableMouseTracking": true,
            "shadow": false,
            "marker": {
                "enabled": true
            }
        }
    },
    "legend": {
        "borderColor": "#000000",
        "borderRadius": 5,
        "borderWidth": 1,
        "useHTML": true,
        "adjustChartSize": true,
        "itemHiddenStyle": {
            "color": "#8e8e8e"
        },
        "itemStyle": {
            "fontWeight": "normal",
            "color": "#274b6d"
        },
        "itemDistance": 10,
        "symbolRadius": 2,
        "alignColumns": false
    },
    "credits": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "type": "datetime",
        "labels": {},
        "showLastLabel": false,
        "tickPositions": [
            1498892400000,
            1530428400000,
            1561964400000,
            1593586800000,
            1625122800000,
            1656658800000,
            1688194800000,
            1719817200000,
            1751353200000,
            1782889200000
        ],
        "endOnTick": true,
        "startOnTick": true,
        "maxPadding": 0,
        "minPadding": 0,
        "tickLength": 5,
        "title": {
            "text": "Fiscal Year",
            "style": {
                "color": "#4d759e",
                "fontWeight": "bold"
            }
        },
        "plotLines": [
            {
                "color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)",
                "width": 1,
                "value": 1561964399999,
                "dashStyle": "longdash"
            },
            {
                "color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)",
                "width": 1,
                "value": 1723558819561,
                "dashStyle": "longdash"
            },
            {
                "color": "rgba(100, 150, 100, 0.5)",
                "width": 1,
                "value": 1751342400000,
                "dashStyle": "longdash"
            },
            {
                "color": "#f28f43",
                "width": 1,
                "value": 1656648000000,
                "dashStyle": "longdash"
            }
        ]
    },
    "yAxis": {
        "tickLength": 5,
        "title": {
            "text": "Annual Energy consumed (kWh)",
            "style": {
                "color": "#4d759e",
                "fontWeight": "bold"
            }
        }
    },
    "series": [
        {
            "type": "line",
            "name": "Consumption (Actual)",
            "color": "#000000",
            "lineWidth": 2,
            "marker": {
                "symbol": "circle"
            },
            "legendIndex": 1,
            "tooltip": {
                "valueDecimals": 0,
                "outside": true,
                "useHTML": true,
                "headerFormat": "<span style=\"font-weight:bold; color:{series.color};\">{series.name}</span><br />"
            },
            "data": [
                [
                    1530428399999,
                    3500000
                ],
                [
                    1561964399999,
                    750000
                ],
                [
                    1561964399999,
                    123000
                ],
                [
                    1593586799999,
                    64436656.991663404
                ],
                [
                    1625122799999,
                    14653553.51
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "spline",
            "name": "Projected consumption (Big Picture: Scenario + Background Projects)",
            "color": "rgb(0, 88, 33)",
            "marker": {
                "symbol": "triangle-down"
            },
            "dashStyle": "Dash",
            "legendIndex": 6,
            "tooltip": {
                "outside": true,
                "useHTML": true,
                "headerFormat": "<span style=\"font-weight:bold; color:{series.color};\">{series.name}</span><br />"
            },
            "data": [
                [
                    1726790400000,
                    -128904043.47014609
                ],
                [
                    1726876800000,
                    -128904043.47014609
                ],
                [
                    1770854400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1770940800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1771027200000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1771113600000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1771200000000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1771286400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1771372800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1771459200000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1771545600000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1771632000000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1771718400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1771804800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1771891200000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1771977600000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1772064000000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1772150400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1772236800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1772323200000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1772409600000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1772496000000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1772582400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1772668800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1772755200000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1772841600000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1772928000000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1773014400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1773100800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1773187200000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1773273600000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1773360000000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1773446400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1773532800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1773619200000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1773705600000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1773792000000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1773878400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1773964800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1774051200000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1774137600000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1774224000000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1774310400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1774396800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1774483200000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1774569600000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1774656000000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1774742400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1774828800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1774915200000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1775001600000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1775088000000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1775174400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1775260800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1775347200000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1775433600000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1775520000000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1775606400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1775692800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1775779200000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1775865600000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1775952000000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1776038400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1776124800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1776211200000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1776297600000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1776384000000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1776470400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1776556800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1776643200000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1776729600000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1776816000000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1776902400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1776988800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1777075200000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1777161600000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1777248000000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1777334400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1777420800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1777507200000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1777593600000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1777680000000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1777766400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1777852800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1777939200000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1778025600000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1778112000000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1778198400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1778284800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1778371200000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1778457600000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1778544000000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1778630400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1778716800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1778803200000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1778889600000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1778976000000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1779062400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1779148800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1779235200000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1779321600000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1779408000000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1779494400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1779580800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1779667200000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1779753600000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1779840000000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1779926400000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ],
                [
                    1780012800000,
                    -129011974.18085411
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "scatter",
            "name": "Progress To Date (Projected)",
            "color": "#000000",
            "marker": {
                "symbol": "circle",
                "radius": 5
            },
            "legendIndex": 7,
            "tooltip": {
                "enabled": true,
                "useHTML": true,
                "outside": true,
                "headerFormat": "<span style=\"font-weight:bold; color:{series.color};\">{series.name}</span><br />"
            },
            "data": [
                [
                    1723558819561,
                    -128904043.47014609
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "scatter",
            "name": "Primary Target",
            "color": "#649664",
            "marker": {
                "symbol": "diamond",
                "radius": 5
            },
            "legendIndex": 10,
            "tooltip": {
                "enabled": true,
                "valueDecimals": 0,
                "useHTML": true,
                "headerFormat": "<span style=\"font-weight:bold; color:{series.color};\">{series.name}</span><br />"
            },
            "data": [
                [
                    1751342400000,
                    100000
                ]
            ]
        }
    ],
    "exporting": {
        "chartOptions": {
            "chart": {
                "reflow": true,
                "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
            }
        },
        "sourceWidth": 1250,
        "sourceHeight": 500,
        "scale": 2,
        "fallbackToExportServer": false,
        "buttons": {
            "contextButton": {
                "enabled": false
            }
        }
    }
});
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/highcharts/adapt-chart-to-legend/master/adapt-chart-to-legend.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>




I tried to reproduce your issue but in my case everything works correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/va9bucr4/ Please share your code with me so I could help more!

@DominikChudy Thanks, I added more context, code and a fiddle. It's caused by the adapt-chart-to-legend plugin

Thanks for the further explanation. I'm afraid that the plugin might not work well as the last commit was 6 years ago, so I suggest removing it. Could you please explain precisely why you added this plugin? We should be able to solve the problem it was addressing in a more reliable way.

@DominikChudy the plugin does exactly what we want it to do aside from recently causing the issue with the bottom border of the legend. The plugin prevents the legend from taking space away from the chart. If you remove the plugin from the JSFiddle linked above you will see that the chart gets short and loses resolution on the y-axis. If you add it back you see that the chart gets its height back and has better resolution on the y axis.

Thanks for the further explanation. Please take a look at my answer.

I noticed that in your case, the problem is with just one pixel. So, the simplest solution, in my opinion, would be to correct translateY value by one pixel (line 28 in the demo below).
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yapcx0bh/
else if (this.options.verticalAlign === 'bottom') {
          translateY = chart.originalChartHeight; // #2
          this.group.attr('translateY', translateY - 1);

          if (this.group.alignAttr) {
            this.group.alignAttr.translateY = translateY;
          }
        }


This does bring the border back, thanks! Any advice on how to add more of a margin beneath the legend without sacrificing chart height?

You can manipulate the this.group.attr('translateY', translateY - 1) value, as I did by subtracting 10 pixels, for example. The chart height remains the same.
